# Beautiful Soup find all values for a given attribute, without specifying the tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to get all values of a certain attribute?

Example:

```
<a title="title-in-a">
  <b title="title-in-b"> ... </b>
  <c title="title-in-c"> ... </c>
  <d name="i-dont-care"> ... </d>
</a>
```

Can I get all titles, even if they are in different tags?

Expected result:

```
['title-in-a', 'title-in-b', 'title-in-c']
```

To get all titles in `<a>`, I know I can do this:

```
for item in soup.find_all('a'):
    print item['title']
```

But how to do it for all tags, even without knowing the tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an attribute selector.

```
titles = [item['title'] for item in soup.select('[title]')]
```

Comment: if you don't mind my asking, why (as in - what is the logic behind) `title` needing to be enclosed in both `'[]'`?

Comment: The [] is a css attribute selector @JackFleeting

Comment: @JackFleeting if you google Mozilla css selectors you get nice documentation

Comment: This seem to work, and also works well with classes or tag names. 
Classes: `soup.select('.myclass')` and Tags: `soup.select('tag')`. Can I replace all `find_all` with `select`?

Comment: Yes you can replace

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there's no error in your code (meaning that the `<b>` and `<c>` tags are enclosed within the `<a>` tag) then:

```
for i in soup4.find_all(title=True):
  print(i)
```

will output:

```
<a title="title-in-a">
<b title="title-in-b"> ... </b>
<c title="title-in-c"> ... </c>
...</a>
<b title="title-in-b"> ... </b>
<c title="title-in-c"> ... </c>
```

If, on the other hand, each tag is closed separately, such that the code is:

```
<a title="title-in-a">...</a>
<b title="title-in-b"> ... </b>
<c title="title-in-c"> ... </c>
```

the output is:

```
<a title="title-in-a">...</a>
<b title="title-in-b"> ... </b>
<c title="title-in-c"> ... </c>
```

Comment: This don't seem to work if there is a child without the `title` attribute. See the new example after my edit.

Comment: It's the same question, I just changed the example because I tried your answer and it worked only in the example, but not on a real case, in which there are many tags with multiple children.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your use-case. There is one default method called attrs which will get all the attributes as dict {'name':'value'}

```
response = '''<a title="title-in-a">
  <b title="title-in-b"> ... </b>
  <c title="title-in-c"> ... </c>
  <d name="i-dont-care"> ... </d>
</a>'''
total_attributes = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
for tags in soup.find_all():
    attributes = tags.attrs
    #some filtering goes here 
    if attributes:
        required = list(attributes.values())
        total_attributes = total_attributes + required
print(total_attributes)
```

you can expect result like, also you can do filtering on highlighted place.

```
['title-in-a', 'title-in-b', 'title-in-c', 'i-dont-care']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python `lambda` function to search tag attribute `title`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<a title="title-in-a">
  <b title="title-in-b"> ... </b>
  <c title="title-in-c"> ... </c>
</a>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all(lambda tag:[tag.attrs=='title']):
  print(item['title'])
```

Output:

```
title-in-a
title-in-b
title-in-c
```

Comment: This only seem to work if all tags have attribute `title`. I added different tag to `data` like `<d name="i-dont-care"> ... </d>` and it crashed.

Comment: yes you are right in that case css selector is the right choice.